# Spark Create new column containing min and max of corresponding values in certain other column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have a column

```
    import spark.implicits._
    
    val simpleData = Seq(("James", "Sales", 3000),
        ("Michael", "Sales", 4600),
        ("Robert", "Sales", 4100),
        ("Maria", "Finance", 3000),
        ("James", "Sales", 3000),
        ("Scott", "Finance", 3300),
        ("Jen", "Finance", 3900),
        ("Jeff", "Marketing", 3000),
        ("Kumar", "Marketing", 2000),
        ("Saif", "Sales", 4100))
        
    val df_1 = simpleData.toDF("employee_name", "department", "salary")
```

```
+-------------+----------+------+
|employee_name|department|salary|
+-------------+----------+------+
|        James|     Sales|  3000|
|      Michael|     Sales|  4600|
|       Robert|     Sales|  4100|
|        Maria|   Finance|  3000|
|        James|     Sales|  3000|
|        Scott|   Finance|  3300|
|          Jen|   Finance|  3900|
|         Jeff| Marketing|  3000|
|        Kumar| Marketing|  2000|
|         Saif|     Sales|  4100|
+-------------+----------+------+
```

I an ideal case I would like to add columns `min_department_salary` `max_department_salary` `min_salary_employee_name` and `max_salary_employee_name` to that original dataframe. These would tell for every row for what is min and max salary, who is getting it.

So first row would be `James, Sales, 3000, 3000, 4600, James, Michael`

What I have now is

```
    val df_1_5 = df_1.groupBy('department)
                    .agg(min('salary).as("min_department_salary"), max('salary).as("max_department_salary"))
```

```
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|department|min_department_salary|max_department_salary|
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|     Sales|                 3000|                 4600|
|   Finance|                 3000|                 3900|
| Marketing|                 2000|                 3000|
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

This is not quite there yet and I have tried `join` in there with the original df. I would like to avoid joins as I have a quite big dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `struct` to preserve the other column as below

```
df1.withColumn("sal-name", struct($"salary", $"employee_name"))
  .groupBy('department)
  .agg(min("sal-name").as("min"), max("sal-name").as("max"))
  .select($"department", $"min.*", $"max.*")
  .toDF("department", "min_sal", "min_sal_name", "max_sal", "min_sal_name")
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----------+-------+------------+-------+------------+
|department|min_sal|min_sal_name|max_sal|min_sal_name|
+----------+-------+------------+-------+------------+
|Sales     |3000   |James       |4600   |Michael     |
|Finance   |3000   |Maria       |3900   |Jen         |
|Marketing |2000   |Kumar       |3000   |Jeff        |
+----------+-------+------------+-------+------------+
```

If you want all the rows then you can use `window` function instead of `groupBy`

```
val window = Window.partitionBy("department")

df1.withColumn("sal-name", struct($"salary", $"employee_name"))
  .withColumn("min", min("sal-name").over(window))
  .withColumn("max", max("sal-name").over(window))
  .select($"employee_name", $"department", $"min.*", $"max.*")
  .toDF("employee_name" ,"department", "min_sal", "min_sal_name", "max_sal", "min_sal_name")
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-------------+----------+-------+------------+-------+------------+
|employee_name|department|min_sal|min_sal_name|max_sal|min_sal_name|
+-------------+----------+-------+------------+-------+------------+
|James        |Sales     |3000   |James       |4600   |Michael     |
|Michael      |Sales     |3000   |James       |4600   |Michael     |
|Robert       |Sales     |3000   |James       |4600   |Michael     |
|James        |Sales     |3000   |James       |4600   |Michael     |
|Saif         |Sales     |3000   |James       |4600   |Michael     |
|Maria        |Finance   |3000   |Maria       |3900   |Jen         |
|Scott        |Finance   |3000   |Maria       |3900   |Jen         |
|Jen          |Finance   |3000   |Maria       |3900   |Jen         |
|Jeff         |Marketing |2000   |Kumar       |3000   |Jeff        |
|Kumar        |Marketing |2000   |Kumar       |3000   |Jeff        |
+-------------+----------+-------+------------+-------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Window aggregate functions than regular aggregate functions.

```
val df2 = df1.sort($"department",$"salary")
                 .withColumn("min_department_salary",min("salary") over Window.partitionBy($"department"))
                 .withColumn("max_department_salary",max("salary") over Window.partitionBy($"department"))
                 .withColumn("min_salary_employee_name",first("employee_name") over Window.partitionBy($"department"))
                 .withColumn("max_salary_employee_name",last("employee_name") over Window.partitionBy($"department"))
                 .select("employee_name", "department", "salary",
                         "min_department_salary","max_department_salary",
                         "min_salary_employee_name","max_salary_employee_name")
```